# An exercise in reflexivity of a normed space

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $X$ be a  reflexive normed space.Prove that $\forall x^* \in X^*,\exists x \in X$ such that $||x_0||=1$ and $x^*(x_0)=||x^*||$.

Can someone give a hint to solve this?

A normed space is reflexive iff $J(X)=X^{**}$ where $J(x)=t_x$ and $t_x:X^* \longrightarrow F$(a field) and $t_x(x^*)=x^*(x)$

In other words $t_x \in X^{**}$

I do not want a full solution just a hint to start with.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition of the dual norm, there exists a sequence $\{x_n\}\subset X$ with $\|x_n\|\le1$ such that $x^*(x_n)\to\|x^*\|$. What does $X$ being reflexive tell you about this sequence?

Comment: By reflexivity we have that $x^*(x_n)=t_{x_n}(x^*) \longrightarrow ||x^*||$

Comment: And also that $1=||x_n||=||t_{x_n}||$

Comment: Are you familiar with the Banach-Alaoglu theorem? What does it imply for reflexive spaces?

Comment: yes im familiar but this exercise was indicated from my instructor way before we learned the banach alaoglu theorem.so i want to solve it without this

Comment: Can you guide me further?

Comment: Fair enough, it is not the simplest way but the first that came to mind for me. Have you tried using Jonas Lenz's hint? Specifically, apply the Hahn-Banach theorem to $X^*$.

Comment: i thought that many times but can the Hahn-Banach theorem be used in the dual space of $X$ ?..if it is then i can try it.

Comment: Of course, $X^*$ is a Banach space.

Comment: How about defining a subspace of $X^*$  and work there?For example $B=\{ax^*|a \in F\}$ and an the linear functional $x^{**}(ax^*)=a||x^*||$ and then use the Hahn-Banach theorem for $x^{**}$ and the reflexivite of the space $X$?

Comment: Is this idea valid?

Comment: A well-known corollary of the Hahn-Banach theorem is, if $x\in X$, $x\neq0$, there exist $x^*\in X^*$ such that $\|x^*\|=1$ and $x^*(x)=\|x\|$. Can you see how this applies here?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly right.

Comment: Yes i see ,thank you for your help?

Comment: your hint was to use the Alaoglu theorem which states that the unit ball of $X^*$ is weakly$-*$ compact?

Comment: So the solution must be according to the corollary you mentioned above something like this:  If $x* \in X^*$ then by the corollary $\exists z^{**} \in X^{**}$ such that $z^{**}(x^*)=||x^*||$ and $||z^**||=1$.By reflexivity we have that $z^{**}=t_{x_0}$ for some $x_0 \in X$ thus $||x^*||=z^{**}(x^*)=t_{x_0}(x^*)=x^*(x_0)$ and also we know that $1=||z^{**}||=||t_{x_0}||=||x_0||$ thus we proved the existence of a point in the unit ball in $X$ with the desired property.

Comment: Yes, that's right. My idea with Banach-Alaoglu was this: in a reflexive space, the unit ball is weakly compact, so $x_n\rightharpoonup x$ along a subsequence. This means $x^*(x_n)\to x^*(x)$, so $x^*(x)=1$. You then need to argue $\|x\|=1$ but this is not difficult.

Comment: Ok thank you for your help.. i will accept your answer because i had already thought the Hahn-Banach for the dual space ..just i was not sure if i could you the theorem in the second dual space..but i also want to see the other solution with Banach-Alaoglu theorem.

Answer (score 2):

What does reflexivity tell you? Try to apply the Hahn-Banach Theorem.

Comment: i edited just now

Comment: Now try to use hahn-banach on the dual of X.

Comment: i don't think we can use hahn banach on the dual space..

Comment: Because the OP asks for "just a hint", it might be marginally acceptable to give a response as short as this.  However capitalization and other formatting (using complete sentences) are still a good improvement.

Comment: I do know that, but I am currently just online with my mobile and wanted to answer him nevertheless but thanks for your advices.